# Single Package Transformer

Tags: power-supply

I have very limited space in my project (0.75" x 1.5" x 1.25") to add a remote led light. Looking for a single unit self contained with the following parameters, so I can simply connect the input of the unit directly to the AC switch and output directly to the led wires: Anyone know of a unit that could do this? Or how to build one that would fit the allottedpace?

Convert 120/240 VAc 50/60Hz  to  5Vdc  0.45 amp ( single led requires 3.3V DC)

Thanks

Comment: some sort of "USB-shaped  charger" should fit that requirement

Comment: Welcome to EESE but please note that direct shopping questions will result in fairly prompt closure of your question as per [site rules](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Regarding your question: why not use the guts of a mobile phone charger? These are much lighter and more efficient than a transformer (an iron cored AC/AC device). Make sure you have a fuse in the mains side.

Answer (score 1):

You don't state what sort of space it is: If it's a PCB then something like

https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/embedded-switch-mode-power-supplies-smps/6675760/

would give you 500mA of 5V (and would be superior to a dirt cheap usb adaptor), you'd then just need a resistor from that to power your led.

If your led is well enough insulated you can power it directly from mains AC: you'll need a resistor to keep the forward current down, and a diode to keep the reverse voltage down, or you can buy a pre-packaged LED with all the components inside eg.

https://cpc.farnell.com/camdenboss/cbpi22-230-rd/22mm-indicator-led-pilot-light/dp/MC02599

You could also use a neon indicator like the following

https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/visual-communications-company-vcc/1050QA1/1050QA1-ND/3150873

Comment: I found this old LG usb charger that I can make fit the space. I have a 1/2W 28 Ohm resistor which I think will work.

Input 120/240 Vac  0.2/2A
Output 5.1 Vdc  0.7A

Any comments or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks for the help.